# Generate labels and textbox in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Labels and textbox are dynamically generating in a asp.net form and the records are displaying in labels from sql database, but all records are displaying in one line(there is no break line), I need every record should be displayed in each label with new line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHB0d.jpg)
I would strongly appreciate it if you could reply me back.

here is the screenshot of the code.

Comment: Do you have your code? You can post it together with your question. In fact, that is how normally a questioner asks a question in StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks, added the screenshot of the code.

Comment: @Hadia Please add the code, not a screenshot of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<br />` to separate lines.

Or if your data generally conforms to a tabular format, use a `<table>` structure to arrange fields.

Answer (score 0):

Put the structure inside `<table>` and each row inside a `<tr>` and individual labels inside `<td>`.